# C++ Builder событие OnKeyPress

Tags: c++builder

Всем доброго времени суток. Как в `OnKeyPress` запретить ввод определенного символа первым? Мне необходимо запретить ввод первым символом точку. Вот код:

```
if((Key >= '0' && Key <= '9') || Key == VK_BACK ||Key == '.' || Key == ',') 
  {
   if(Key == ',') 
      Key = '.';
  }
else
Key = NULL;
```

Еще, как запретить ввод подряд двух точек?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не помню точно, как из текстбокса получить его содержимое, но смысл
должен быть ясен.* Ну и, естественно, это распространяется не только на текстбокс.

```
if (textBox->Contents->Length == 0 && Key == '.')
{
    Key = 0;
}

// Дальше уже обработка нормальных клавиш - то, что написано у вас.
```

Comment: что-то у моего эдита нет Contents(

Comment: @чипик Ну я же сказал, что не помню как там :) Может там, `Text` или еще как-нибудь. Это же можно в `property editor` посмотреть.

Comment: OnChange - это то? вроде работает)

Comment: ой нет, не то:(

Comment: SelStart!!!Спасибо!